# Jordan form of $T^{-1}$ if $T=I-D$ where $D$ is the differential operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form

**Here is the question**:  Let $V_n$ be the vector space of polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ of degree less than or equal $n$. Let the operator $T:V_n\to V_n$ be defined by $T(p):=p-p'$, where $p'$ denotes the derivative of $p$. Write the Jordan form of $T^{-1}$.

I only have able to show that all the eigenvalues of $T$ are $1$, because if $Tp=\lambda p$, then $p-p'=\lambda p$, and so by comparing the degree of $p$, $\lambda =1$. That means $det (T)=1$ and so $T$ is invertible.

In fact, I believe $T^{-1}$ is a polynomial in $T$, as $T=I-D$, then $T^{-1}=(I-D)^{-1}=\sum_{k=0}^n D^k=\sum_{k=0}^n (I-T)^k$.

I also noticed that, $det(T^{-1})=1$ since $det(T)=1$.

However, I am not sure how to find out its Jordan form. Any help is appreciated, Thanks a lot!

Comment: so, if I take as basis $\{ 1,x,x^2,..., x^n \}$ what is the matrix for the linear transformation $D \; ?$

Comment: I think the matrix for $D$ will be $1,2,3,...,n-1,n$ in the superdiagonal, all other entries are zeros? @WillJagy

Comment: Sounds right. Now solve your problem for $n = 1,2,3,$ and see what happens; there is some stuff with factorials. Note that $D^2$ has entries in the second superdiagonal, $D^3$ on the third, which shows nicely that it is nilpotent

Comment: Thank you Will, I believe $D^2$ will be $1\cdot 2, 2\cdot 3, ..., (n-1)\cdot n$ in the second superdiagonal, and zeros in all other entries. $D^3$ will be $1\cdot 2\cdot 3, 2\cdot 3\cdot 4, ..., (n-2)\cdot (n-1)\cdot n$ in the third superdiagonal, and zeros in all other entries. So do you  mean I can find out what $T^{-1}$ looks like, then use that to find its Jordan form? It looks like $T^{-1}$  is upper-triangular , with  zeors in its diagonal, and the $n$-th superdiagonal are the $n$-th superdiagonal entries of $D^n$, but how can I get its Jordan form from this? @WillJagy

Comment: I see. If you have never actually calculated the Jordan form of a matrix, see the examples linked in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2749258/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-diagonal-matrices/2749271#2749271

Comment: Thanks a lot, Will